# How can I access the library link after installing using anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, package-managers, hdf

I installed the `hdf5` library using miniconda.

Now, I have to do `EXPORT LIB_HDF5=/XYZ/`

But I don't get anything when I try `which hdf5`

However, I can see hdf5 when I do `conda env list`

This is the first time I am using conda outside of managing Python packages.

Would appreciate any pointers!

Comment: Dummy suggestion just to make sure, do you think we should `activate` something?

Comment: My environment is activated...

Answer (score 1):

`which` searches for executable commands, not for libraries.

If the environment is activated, your library is somewhere in `$CONDA_PREFIX/`.

```
find $CONDA_PREFIX/ -name \*hdf5\*.so
```